# CPython Build fails _ctypes and ssl

Tags: python, pandas, cpython

I'm building CPython to use for building Pandas.

I've forked, cloned and configured `CPython`.

running `make -s -j2`

returns: `Python build finished successfully` along with some expected missing optional modules.

but also includes

```
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible with libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host()
```

Is it ok to skip this module for the purposes of compiling Pandas?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and making again but got the same result.

```
dpkg -l | grep -i openssl
```

returns

```
ii openssl     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3
```

so maybe I just need to point OpenSSL at the newly installed LibreSSL?

Thanks for all suggestions